# How to correctly multiply two long long ints?

Tags: c, multiplication, unsigned-long-long-int

I want to multiply long numbers which are given in a 2^32 basis. I already thought of an nice algorithm to do that, but unfortunatly I'm stuck. The situation I'm stuck at, is how I do multiply two long ints and represent it on the 2^32 basis.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
typedef unsigned int uint32;
typedef unsigned long long uint64;
int main(int argc, char* argv[] )
{

  uint64 a = (uint64)ULONG_MAX;
  printf("%llu\n", a);
  uint64 b = (uint64)ULONG_MAX;  
  printf("%llu\n", b);  
  uint64 c = (uint64)(a*b);

  printf("%llu\n", c);  // prints 1. that would be to lower 32 bits of the results. the upper half is 0xFFFFFFFE

  printf("%llu\n", ULLONG_MAX);
  system("pause");
}
```

Why is ULLONG_MAX the same as ULONG_MAX ? According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limits.h#Member_constants it should be 18,446,744,073,709,551,615  I

As you can see from my comments, I want the result of the the multiplikation in the two uint32.
The lowerhalf would be 0x1 and the upper half 0xFFFFFFFE. How do I get these values?

(I found this question on SO, but it's not helpful in my situation because the answers given ar similiar to my ideas: [Multiplying two long long ints C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856264/multiplying-two-long-long-ints-c))

**Edit:**
My system is Windows XP 32 Bit. I'm using gcc 3.4.2 (mingw-special)

The output I do get while running the code:

```
4294967295
4294967295
1
4294967295
```

**Edit2:**

```
  printf("%i\n", sizeof(unsigned long));
  printf("%i\n", sizeof(unsigned long long));
```

returns

```
4
8
```

**Edit 3:**
Thanks to Petesh I was able to find the solution:

```
  printf("%lu\n", c & 0xFFFFFFFF);
  printf("%lu\n", (c >> 32));
```

Comment: What implementation are you using? This works fine for me on GCC (32 bit system). Prints 4294967295, 4294967295, 18446744065119617025, 18446744073709551615 as expected. Possibly your implementation doesn't support the %llu print format, is treating it like %lu, and your system is little-endian so in both cases varargs happens to pick up the less-significant word of the argument?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The hint is in the system("pause") - you're on windows? Printing a long long using the Microsoft visual c runtime requires using '%I64u' (that's a capital i).

This is based on SO question [How do you printf an unsigned long long int(the format specifier for unsigned long long int)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844/how-do-you-printf-an-unsigned-long-long-int)

Comment: I kind of expected that, once I saw that he was using mingw.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why you're getting those results with your (unspecified) compiler but `gcc` under Ubuntu 10 gives:

```
4294967295
4294967295
18446744065119617025
18446744073709551615
```

with those last two being `0xfffffffe00000001` and (2<sup>64</sup>-1) respectively, as you desire.

So maybe consider switching to a more up-to-date compiler. It may be you're using a pre-C99 compiler.

Just out of interest, what does `sizeof (unsigned long)` and `sizeof (unsigned long long)` give you on your system. This would go a long way towards explaining your problem.

---

A couple of other things to check since your `sizeof`s seem to indicate the data types themselves are okay (though these may not fix the problem - they were found with a [fairly shallow web search](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/60111-displaying-long-long-printf.html)):

- Try using `"%I64u"` as the format string instead of `"%llu"`. If MinGW is using the MSVCRT libs, that might be required for real 64-bit `printf` support.
- Make sure you're compiling with `-std=c99`.